# SQL query to select columns from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to start using subqueries which to this point I haven't needed to. If I have these tables:

```
Books
--Id (Primary Key)
--Title (string)
--GenreId (Foreign Key)
```

and

```
Genre
--Id (Primary Key)
--Name (string)
```

I know that if I want to retrieve Title and Name, then I can run this query:

```
select b.Title, g.Name from Books b
join Genre g on b.GenreId=g.Id
```

What I am trying to do is understand the difference between that and this:

```
select b.Title from Books b
join (
    select g.Id, g.Name from Genre g
)
as ge
on b.GenreId=ge.Id
go
```

I want to know why the second query only gives me the Title column from Books and not the Id or Name columns from Genre? My question really is how can I turn the first query into a subquery and retrieve the same results? I want both Title from Books, and Name from Genre.

Comment: *"I want to know why the second query only gives me the Title column from Books and not the Id or Name columns from Genre"* What else would you expect with just `select b.Title from`... If I asked you to pick up "the book" from the table, where there is a book, pen and pad of paper, and then asked you "why didn't you pick up the pen and paper" would you blame yourself for not doing so?

Comment: I was expecting that those results would come from the inner select statement. Which was the reason for the question.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if you said "pick up the book, then pick up the pen and paper", and I only picked up the book, we would be wondering why I didn't also pick up the pen and paper. This was the point of my question and my misunderstanding.

Comment: But that *isn't* what I ask, and nor is it what you asked.

Comment: I asked why the second query in my question does not give me all of the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query only gives you the title because that is all you asked for.

The outermost `select` describes the result set you are getting.  Other `select`s are used for the processing logic but don't affect the columns being returned.

Comment: Okay, so could I do the same thing but put the columns from the second table in the outer select? Also I assume then that purpose of a subquery is to use a where or some other sort of logic? If so, then this example of a subquery would be rather useless.

Comment: Based on this information I solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  select G.name, B.title from Books B left join Genre G On G.ID = B.GenreId
```

Comment: The other answer solved my misunderstanding. I now know that only the outer select will get the columns and the inner is for logic. I was trying to better understand subqueries.